# MySQL table relations - join if field has value

Tags: mysql, join

There could be X different tables in my system and one table that stores all relation data of those tables. For example the database could look like this

```
--------------------------        -----------------------------------
| Table fruits           |        |  Table drinks                   |
--------------------------        -----------------------------------
| id    | name           |        | id   | name                     |
--------------------------        -----------------------------------
| 1     | banana         |        | 1    | strawberry apple cocktail|
| 2     | apple          |        | 2    | banana juice             |
| 3     | strawberry     |        | 3    | cola                     |
--------------------------        -----------------------------------

--------------------------
| table food             |
--------------------------
| id    |  name          |
--------------------------
| 1     | apple  pie     |
--------------------------
```

And the table for the relations contains the id and the table name from both entries.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| table relations                                |
--------------------------------------------------
| id  | table_1    | id_1   | table_2     | id_2 | 
--------------------------------------------------
| 1   | fruits     | 1      | drinks      | 2    | banana + banana juice
| 2   | fruits     | 2      | drinks      | 1    | apple + s.a. cocktail
| 3   | fruits     | 3      | drinks      | 1    | strawberry + s.a cocktail
| 4   | food       | 1      | fruits      | 2    | apple pie + apple
| 5   | drinks     | 3      | food        | 1    | if someone wants to mix it
--------------------------------------------------
```

If I have a drink (strawberry apple cocktail) I want to get all fruit ids that belong to it (strawberry and apple) and the other way around when I have a fruit (strawberry) I would like to query for all related drink ids.
So I need one query structure to find both sides and since it is all dynamic I can't know if the fruit is in `table_1` or `table_2` (otherwise it would be simple)

I would like to have something like this (attention pseudocode) to query all ids from drinks that contain bananas (table: fruits, id: 1)

```
SELECT id
FROM drinks
LEFT JOIN relations AS rel ON drinks.id = (rel.table_1 == drinks)? rel.id_1 : rel.id_2
WHERE
((rel.id_1 = '1' AND rel.table_1 = 'fruits') OR ( rel.id_2 = '1' AND rel.table_2 = 'fruits' ))
```

**My issues**

1. When I join my relation table only one time, I would have to query two times since I don't know if I have to join it on id_1 or id_2
2. When I do 2 Joins like this

   `Select * from drinks
   LEFT JOIN relations AS relation1 ON drinks.id = relation1.id_1
   LEFT JOIN relations AS relation2 ON drinks.id = relation2.id_2
   WHERE
      ( (relation1.id_1 = '1'
        AND relation1.table_1 = 'fruits')
      OR ( relation2.id_2 = '1'
          AND relation2.table_2 = 'fruits' )
      OR ( relation1.id_2 = '1'
          AND relation1.table_2 = 'fruits')
      OR ( relation2.id_1 = '1'
          AND relation2.table_1 = 'fruits'))`

   I can search for everything from both sides (have drinks -> receive fruits / have fruit -> receive drinks) but I get also the drink with the same Id like the fruit

   3. I would like to avoid to `select * from relations` since I build the query with php with other conditions like fruit name, dateCreated and so on and I would have to restructure the entire query  if it contains relations

      You can download the mysql dump [here](http://anubarak16.bplaced.net/relationtest.sql) to test it. I hope someone could be so kind to help me.

Thank you and sry for my bad english

Comment: I suggest you to remove this relations table and  create 3 new tables instead: fruit_drink_relations, food_drinks_relations and fruit_food_relations.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to avoid since I'll need to create tons of relationtables that way

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your design, the `drink` table has many-to-many relation with `fruit` table, so you should separate fruit_drink_relation's table.

The same many-to-many relation exist for fruit_drink_food_relation's table.

To  look for food, query the second relation's table, otherwise, the first relation table is enough.

Comment: Every table should be connectable with each other. So if you create 10 different tables you should be able to create relations with the others. I think it would be easier to insert each relation twice - in both orders - than to create so many. But thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Utterly bad design there.

See, the Relational Database Management Systems possess the powerful mechanism of keeping and enforcing **consistent** (!) relationships between entities (represented as records in the tables).

Why not use it as it is?

You got n..n (many-to-many) relationships, not more than that, as seen from examples.

There's a more-than-common pattern for it, the relation table that essentially consists of two columns both of which are foreign keys to the entities you'd need to connect together:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits_juices (
   fruit_id INT,
   juice_id INT
   FOREIGN KEY fruit_id
       REFERENCES fruits(id),
   FOREIGN KEY juice_id
       REFERENCES juices(id)
)
```

Do that for each relation you need - and this it.

And that is nothing bad in creating a couple of relationships - that's the way RDBMS supposed to work (hence what they're best at).

Don't try to be unnecessary versatile: your use cases don't demand that whatsoever.

Too one-for-all solutions are usually not good in all the cases they suppose to cover and have an additional maintenance cost to keep them from falling apart (data consistency, in your case)

Comment: I know that and this is what I usually do and what I advice everyone else to do but this time I want to try something different. It is more or less just a test for myself to create a cms that gets rid of the "huge table problem" from craft cms. However with the usual method I'm not really able to create a formbuilder that can link to every other form

Comment: Oh, so that was just for the sake of trying something. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [snowflake schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema).

Looks like currently you are -in the ugly- half way of that.